# Sending goal without executing plan

Tags: ros-noetic, planner

I am using ROS Noetic and I want create a script that defines an end position but I only want to retrieve the plan-intermediate-points and save them as a list in an array.

I wrote a python file that sends a goal to `MoveBaseGoal` but as soon the goal is sent `move_base` starts executing the plan. I also have a callback to the `/move_base/DWAPlannerROS/local_plan` topic to retrieve the waypoints working well.

So the question is, how do I sent an end position (x,y,θ), create a plan using a planner of `move_base` but don't execute the plan?

Comment: https://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Services - look at the make_plan service, That might be what you need.